# Wir wurden überrannt. Die Leute sind über ihrem Umgang mit Smartphones verunsichert

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the word "überrannt"? whenever I search for for it in any dictionary, it ends by the verb überrennen.

Comment: I have no idea, what could it "überrannt" mean here. I only see that it is a perfekt-form of a verb. Maybe "overwhelmed" or similar could it be. Even if this post is a translation request, may I ask a simple word from a native speaker? :-)

Comment: See http://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch-verb-%C3%BCberrennen.html

Comment: And also https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/%C3%BCberrennen

Answer (score 4):

> it ends by the verb überrennen.

<strike>"überrannt" is the past of "überrennen".</strike>
In this phrase "überrannt" is the passive form of "überrennen", that's why dictionaries take you there.

In this context "überrennen" is figurative. It means something comes quite fast and unexpected, it overstrains one's mind or capabilities. There is no time to get prepared and react appropriately to a situation.
I think this expression has no present form, there is only this past form "überrannt werden".

Perhaps these two phrases shall say: the smartphones came too fast, there was no chance to prepare and handling them is too much for the people.

It's not this question's topic but the second phrase is wrong. It must be "über ihre**n**". It still sounds odd to me, I have no exact idea what this phrase wants to express.

### Edit

I searched for this phrase and found an article that could be your source.
It talks about an app that examines user behavior on smartphones.
"wir wurden überrannt" - they didn't expect so many users would join this research and use the app.
Then: this (the amount of people that joined) shows that ...

Comment: Thank you so much .... May be I made a mistake while I changed the sentence by myself. The original sentence is: "Wir wurden überrannt", sagt er. "Das zeigt, dass die Leute über ihrem Umgang mit diesen Geräten verunsichert sind"

Comment: See my edit. Btw it really is ihre**n**

Comment: Unfortunately, your grammatical analysis is wrong. The form “überrannt” is a past participle, and it is used here for passive voice. Only “wurden” makes it past tense, it could just as well be present tense “werden”.

Comment: @CarstenS You are absolutely right! I only had the single word "überrannt" in mind to explain why it doesn't appear in some dictionaries. But nevertheless this should be expressed correctly. Thanks! I will edit  my text to respect this.